# Android Generating Multiple APKs for Android ABIs (diff CPUs)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, apk

I new-ish to the Android world so I didn't even know this was a thing until today!?

I have released an Android app and one of the users reached out to me letting me know they could not download my app/update since the APK was not available for their phone.

How do I go about configuring my project in Android studio?!

My current Gradle file is :

```
android {

    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.XXX.XXX"
        minSdkVersion 31
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 47 
        versionName "2.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
    
        release {

            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
                'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'

        }

        debug {

            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
                'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'

        }

    }

    compileOptions {

        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17

    }

    namespace 'com.XXX.XXX'

}
```

I have been searching on the web and its seems very confusing in regards to `flavors` , `splits`, `externalNativeBuild` etc...

I guess I am used to iOS where its really is one and done...

Can anyone provide any info on how my gradle file needs to be modified to handle the multiple APKs...

*** as well as once the gradle file is updated and complied how does that get loaded/treated when submitting it to the Google Play store!?

Comment: If you publish the app via Play Store you don't have to care about the libraries and their ABIs. You simply upload an app bundle containing everything and Google generates the APK files required for each device. And if you want to directly provide an APK file you can simply filter the ABIs so only arm64-v8a remains (and may be armv7 if you want to support older devices). The other ABIs are more or less irrelevant as there are no physical devices supporting it.

Comment: Agreed, but they told me that they are not able to see the update on the Play Store due to their CPU... so i am as confused as you...

Comment: You have set `minSdkVersion 31` which means only Android 12+ devices can see and install the app. Most likely they use a device with an older Android version. Google Play Store never tells you why you don't see an app, so they were guessing it is the CPU/ABI.

Comment: Awesome thx, i guess its my fault as well, i thought SDK 31 was Android 11.

Comment: https://apilevels.com